# this is my first program in GUI and it just wont open any window..no error ,nothing.I run it on commandline .what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, user-interface

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class framo extends Frame
{

```
public framo()
{
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
Panel panel=new Panel();
Button btn=new Button("press");
panel.add(btn);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
framo F=new framo();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added the panel to your frame. Also, you need to set size of the frame and make that frame visible.

You can refer to below sample code -

```
    public class Framo extends Frame {

            public Framo() {
                setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                Panel panel = new Panel();
                Button btn = new Button("press");
                panel.add(btn);

                add(panel);
                setSize(400, 400);
                setVisible(true);
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Framo f = new Framo();

            }

   }
```

Also, please follow java variable naming convention.